# jQuery Selector Problem (First TD in each TR in a table)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to add a css class to **the first td (cell)** (and no other td) of **each tr (row)** in my table.

Can someone help me with the jQuery selector for this please?

Thank you!

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why. This must be a one-liner and easy to answer without needing my approach. For arguments sake though, my attempt was table > tr> td but this selected all td's and I didn't get first:child to work right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector:

```
$("table tr td:first-child").text("I am the first child of the row");
```

A little test: http://jsfiddle.net/WxzfQ/

Comment: Ahhh I thought I need the > in there to specify descendants... let me try this :)

Comment: `table > tr` messes up with browsers that like to add `tbody` elements into your markup (firefox and chrome are two culprits).